# image gallery library with pinch to zoom feature

Tags: html

I am looking for an image library with pinch to zoom feature (free or commercial).
I've been using Photoswipe but it doesn't work well on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Touch N Swipe](http://codecanyon.net/item/touch-n-swipe-image-gallery/5886023). It has a commercial license (really cheap), but it works very well. It uses jquery, jquery.hammer and jquery.mouseweel.